# How to create a various type of cells in a single tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm currently developing an app which has features like half Uber, half Tinder.

I would like to create a TableView for editing profile to make it look like a view of Tinder's profile editing view.

I successfully made a first cell for picking up profile image and second cell for textLabel.

I want to make a third cell which has an editable TextView(not textField so users can enter several lines of words) But the codes aren't working as I intended.

It seems like although I made a textView in my Custom Cell Class and set it to my third tableView cell in my tableViewController class, it doesn't appear on my simulator.

I'm still not quite sure what's the good way to make several types of cell for a single tableView so if there's other better way to do it, I would love to know.

My codes related to this issue is below.

> ViewController

```
//EditProfileViewController For The Profile Edit view
class EditProfileViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

> TableViewController

```
//MyTableViewController for the EditProfileViewController
class EditProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 5
    } else if section == 1 {
        return 2
    } else {
        return 4
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //link my custom Cell here
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as?  MyCellTableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            if indexPath.row  == 0 {
                //this row is for an Image Picker
                cell.textLabel?.text = "edit profile image"
            } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                //this row is just like a title of third cell which is editable self description
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Describe yourself"
                cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
                //this row is an editable self description
                cell.addSubview(cell.selfDescritionTextView)
                cell.selfDescritionTextView.delegate = self
                cell.selfDescritionTextView.isEditable = true
                cell.selfDescritionTextView.text = "Enter some descriptions here"


            }

        }

        else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "section 1"


        }

        else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "section 2"

        }


        return cell
    } else {
        //Just in case
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

}
```

> TableViewCell

```
//MyCellTableViewCell
class MyCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

//create a textView for self description
var selfDescritionTextView = UITextView()

//init
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell")
    selfDescritionTextView = UITextView(frame: self.frame)
    self.addSubview(selfDescritionTextView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

If you need to know more codes than what I showed here, Please let me know.

I'm not obsessed with this method to create my edit profile View so if anyone knows other ways better than this, I would LOVE to know as well.

Thanks

Comment: Are all cells in embedded in the table view? Are all cells have a custom class?

Comment: Can you use breakpoint and check whether the control is coming over cellForRow if condition  :        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as?  MyCellTableViewCell

Comment: And are you using tableview prototype cells in storyboard or custom cell xibs for MyCellTableViewCell?

Comment: >Ahmad F  Since I didn't know I could make several cells in the main storyboard, I just made one cell and gave it the custom class. And in the tableView Controller class, I defined contents for each section and rows so technically all cells embedded in the table view and have the same custom class in my understanding. Does it make any sense?

Comment: >MBN I checked that control is coming to the cellForRow if condition by putting print to console inside of the if statement and it worked! I created a prototype cell in storyboard and made a TableViewCell file for the cell and set the reuseidentifier in the file to link them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: TableViewCell1.NibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell1.Identifier)
   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: TableViewCell2.NibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell2.Identifier)
   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: TableViewCell3.NibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell3.Identifier)
}
```

You'll have 3 Custom Table View Cells, with its subviews, respectively:

```
class MyCellTableViewCell1: UITableViewCell {
   static var NibName: String = String(describing: TableViewCell1.self)
   static var Identifier: String = "TableViewCell1"

   func configure() { ... }
}
```

Then:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell: UITableViewCell
   // link my custom Cell here. 

   if indexPath.row  == 0, let dequeuedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell1.Identifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell1 {
      dequeuedCell.configure()
      cell = dequeuedCell
   }
   else if indexPath.row  == 1, let dequeuedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell2.Identifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell2 {
      dequeuedCell.configure()
      cell = dequeuedCell
   }
   else if indexPath.row  == 2, let dequeuedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell3.Identifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell3 {
      dequeuedCell.configure()
      cell = dequeuedCell
   }
   else {
      cell = UITableViewCell()
   }


   return cell

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! from all comments here, it seems like I need to make 3 cells in storyboard and give reuseidentifier each! and then make custom cell respectively. To be honest, I didn't know that I can create cells more than one in the storyboard(so I was struglling with making several cells with only one prototype cell...)! I'll try it! thank you so much again!!

Answer (score 1):

Register multiple nib files like this , but it in **viewDidLoad**

```
  tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier1)

  tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell2", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier2)

  tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell3", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier3)
```

Comment: I registered my cellClass in my tableViewController class (viewDidLoad) and the textView appeared indeed!! but it appeared on the first cell which used to be an image picker. I guess its because I defined the textView in the custom cell file but defined an image picker(first row cell) in my tableViewController? I'm using only one prototype cell which has reuseidentifier so it might be causing it too...